# Bibdesk "convert files" removes DOI from entries - recovery possible?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, doi, bibdesk

Bibdesk's (1.6.2 (3071)) "Convert Files" function removes DOIs from all found entries and instead assigns them as links. This is nice to have, but I want to include the DOIs in my references (APA-Style). But the DOI entry fields are removed during the process.

Is there a way to get them back without doing it manually? 
How do I avoid this in the future?

Comment: Well the obvious way is to make BibDesk to the proper thing (not turn DOIs into URL) (I have no idea how to do that, though). In the mean time there is a way to remap these URLs to DOIs if you use `biblatex` with `biber`. If you use `bibtex` and an APA-style cite package, it will be very hard to do this. Anyway a full MWE (including a sample `.bib` entry as well as a short sample document, so we can see what packages you use to get the bibliography) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for BibDesk.